# How to setup datacontext and custom usercontrol binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding, user-controls

I do not understand why binding works for a Textbox but does not work for usercontrol.
On image below you see how it should work. The service can bind to the yellow usercontrol and this usercontrol contains a property of my own class. In my case this property is called *Email*. Problem is, that this *Email* is never bind to the yellow usercontrol.
If I replace the usercontrol by simple "*TextBox*" control, it works proper.

Please can you advice me how to get Binding work?

[image: User control description of binding]

**Codebehind of Silvelright Main Page**

```
#Region "UserProfile"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' UserProfile Dependency Property
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared ReadOnly UserProfileProperty As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("UserProfile", GetType(ServiceReference1.UserProfile), GetType(MainPage), _
            New Windows.PropertyMetadata(Nothing, _
                AddressOf OnUserProfileChanged))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the UserProfile property.  This dependency property 
    ''' indicates ....
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property UserProfile() As ServiceReference1.UserProfile
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(UserProfileProperty), ServiceReference1.UserProfile)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ServiceReference1.UserProfile)
            SetValue(UserProfileProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handles changes to the UserProfile property.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Overloads Shared Sub OnUserProfileChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim target As MainPage = CType(d, MainPage)
        Dim oldUserProfile As ServiceReference1.UserProfile = CType(e.OldValue, ServiceReference1.UserProfile)
        Dim newUserProfile As ServiceReference1.UserProfile = target.UserProfile
        target.OnUserProfileChanged(oldUserProfile, newUserProfile)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Provides derived classes an opportunity to handle changes to the UserProfile property.
    ''' </summary>
    Protected Overridable Overloads Sub OnUserProfileChanged(ByVal oldUserProfile As ServiceReference1.UserProfile, ByVal newUserProfile As ServiceReference1.UserProfile)
        Me.DataContext = newUserProfile

    End Sub

#End Region
```

when tracking the property, the "newUserProfile" item was set successfully in codebehind.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CH_App.ucUserEditor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                          xmlns:my="clr-namespace:CH_App"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
        <my:ucDbRow Title="Email" Value="{Binding Path=Email, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Texbox with binding of email works like it should and shows the email address.
The usercontrol does not show the email address. The user control shows the Title correct.

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CH_App.ucDbRow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:CH_App"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Codebehind of usercontrol**

```
#Region "Title"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Title Dependency Property
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared ReadOnly TitleProperty As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", GetType(String), GetType(ucDbRow), _
            New Windows.PropertyMetadata(""))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the Title property.  This dependency property 
    ''' indicates ....
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(TitleProperty), String)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region



#Region "Value"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Value Dependency Property
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(String), GetType(ucDbRow), _
            New Windows.PropertyMetadata(""))

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the Value property.  This dependency property 
    ''' indicates ....
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(ValueProperty), Object)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region
```

Comment: Is this a WPF question or Silverlight one?

Comment: I am working on Silverlight. But last month I had similar problem on WPF but there I did a workaround without Binding. Now I want to fix it because I am sure, I just missed a small piece of declaration. I've now tried several hours with different Binding keywords but it never worked.

Comment: I read the question twice and still don't get what you are trying to do. Provide details of what you want to achieve first.

Comment: thanks for advice. I will update the question by image.

Comment: NP. I think I know what your problem is but I think you are doing things which you should not be. I *think* solving your immediate problem will mean letting you dig yourself into a bigger hole then you already are in.

Comment: Hi NVM: I think Binding is very clear and transparent and I don't feel I am in a hole. But as simple it should work, it just does not do what expected. If you have any item which is wrong or a sample it would be great. I don't like to use templates, I also can share my project for download if you want to see how it works now.

Comment: Ok. I've now updated the question. Thanks again for advice. Otherwise I got downvotes and I don't know why. Your help was fine in that case already.

Comment: Why don't you like templates, they're the obvious way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit (insert):**

You're using Silverlight 4, and i was either testing in Silverlight 5 or WPF from which both probably, but
WPF certainly supports RelativeSourceBinding that way, however you had it almost right.
The output window in Visual Studio gives you the following error if I'm correct.

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error:
>   'Email' property not found on 'VisualBasicSilverlightApplication1.ucDbRow'
>   'VisualBasicSilverlightApplication1.ucDbRow' (HashCode=72766).
>   BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.Email'
>   DataItem='VisualBasicSilverlightApplication1.ucDbRow' (HashCode=72766);
>   target element is 'VisualBasicSilverlightApplication1.ucDbRow' (Name='');
>   target property is 'Value' (type 'System.String')..

The DataContext will fall through the usercontrol, except at the toplevel/instance of the usercontrol.
So instead of doing this:

```
<my:ucDbRow Title="Email" Value="{Binding Path=Email, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The only thing you will have to change in your code is point to the element where you set the DataContext on, which is most of the time the LayoutRoot:
(in ucUserEditor)

```
<my:ucDbRow Title="Email" Value="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, 
            Path=DataContext.Email, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Previous answer**
You are overriding the binded datacontext with this `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in CH_App.ucDbRow. Remove it and the Value works because you've got your underlaying `DataContext` back, however Title is not working anymore.

There is a solution:

Change `ucDbRow` to this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CH_App.ucDbRow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Title}" Height="23"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note: Check your ouput window if Bindings don't work, if it failed it's in the output window.

In addition:

I would suggest **not** to use usercontrol's as control's. In my opinion usercontrols should more be used to represent individual context, not half a context on one and half a context on another. Start looking at usercontrols more as pages and use custom control's and datatemplate's for the detailed work. Also building a better layout is becominging very easy using a `Grid` which is (again in my opinion) one of the best features in WPF and Silverlight, can't be beaten by ordered usercontrols.

Comment: Hi Silvermind. Thanks for your answer. I am with you on usercontrols but it would expand the question if I would explain all here. I also did the stackpanel only for question. I am new in AncestorType using and I already got ERROR message when typing in Silverlight XAML ucDbRow that AncestorType was not found as relative source. Any advice?

Comment: @Nasenbaer Because it needs your namespace. xmnls:local="clr-namespace:mynamespace" and the Ancestortype="{ x:Type local:ucDbRow}"

Comment: Btw: If ucDbRow is a UserControl (as presented in your example xaml I assume yes), than you can also specify the word `UserControl` as the `AncestorType`.

Comment: Perhaps I am thinking too small. But nothing of the ideas worked: I still misunderstand where to change something to avoid the XAML parser error message while binding correct to context. Can you update your sample with more code?

Comment: Did you exactly copy the XAML I provided, because it should definitely work? Unless the ucDbRow is not a UserControl in codebehind, but that should lead to more (different) errors. I do not have the time to create a full example right now. Maybe in about 6 hours.

Comment: @Nasenbaer I've updated my answer and if you like I'll post the entire code I made, but it shouldn't be necessary since the answer should be right this time. :)